# External microphone interfering with macbook speaker volume

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone

I am using 2019 Macbook Pro with macOS Catalina v10.15.7.

I am trying to use external microphone ([Maono AU-400 Lavalier Microphone (Black)](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07JF9B592/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) through audio jack. On connecting the microphone, I change audio settings to use external mac speakers for output and external microphone for input. However, moving or touching microphone often changes speaker volume level. There is no explicit volume control setting on external microphone.

When I connect external microphone, it is shown as "external headphones" in both sound input and output settings. I am guessing the issue is the system is not able to recognize microphone as only input device.

[image]
Is there any advanced configuration which can disable connection between speaker volume level and device connected through audio jack?

Thank you!

Comment: How/where are your external speakers connected? They don't show in your picture. the disturbance is likely that the mic's jack is making poor connection with the socket - needs contact cleaner. The fact the mic shows as a 'ghost' headset is probably the pinout confusing the Mac. The plug 'looks' like a headset plug to the Mac, even though there's nothing connected to the pins.

Comment: @Tetsujin there are no external speakers. I am using Macbook's speakers. I think you are right about the plug confusing Mac. Is there any way to make Mac consider this device as only microphone?

Comment: I don't think the issue is recognition, I think it's an intermittent connection.